# HTML buttons redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

Hope you will be doing well. I'm trying to redirect to another page using button with JS but don't know this piece of code is not working. I need your help regarding this your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<button  id="logoutB" type="button"  name="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-info">Log Out</button>

<script>
    DOCUMENT.getElementById("logoutB").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "logout.php";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document` must be lowercase:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("logoutB").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "logout.php";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Or like this:

```
<button  id="logoutB" type="button"  name="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-info">Log Out</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("logoutB").onclick = function () {
    window.location.assign("logout.php");
};
</script>
```